# Rasterize 2 Billion row parquet dataset

Tags: parquet

I have a parquet dataset containing over two billion rows. The data is of species occurrence records extracted from GBIF, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/download/0004433-240216155721649). I want to produce a raster that contains, for each cell, the number of points that fall in that cell. The coordinate system is wgs84, and the resolution should be 1 km. The dataset includes separate (non-geo-spatial) columns for longitude and latitude. I prefer to use R to run the query, if possible.

My idea is to transform the lon/lat columns into a geometry and run a function like [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to adjust the points to the center of grid cells, group by adjusted lon/lat, perform a count, and output a table that has one row per pixel center with the total count for that cell.

Is this a feasible approach with R or any other technologies? Or is there a better way to achieve this rasterization?